# Swap multiple column values in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update

I am trying to swap multiple column values that were incorrectly swapped due to backend code. I am trying to use the following:

```
UPDATE insured
SET address1=(:risk_address1_var:=address1), address1 = risk_address1, risk_address1 = :risk_address1_var;
```

It's not working like it works for mysql as temp variable(using @). I want to execute this sql query in the liquibase migration code.

Comment: That hack is not needed in Postgres - it properly supports just swapping them in place. The variable is essentially a workaround for a MySQL bug.

Answer (score 1):

No need for a temporary variable. Unlike MySQL, Postgres allows doing what you want with simply:

```
UPDATE insured
SET address1 = risk_address1, risk_address1 = address1;
```